# Plural genetive form of Heschl's gyrus

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I would like to write that a certain group of participants have larger Heschl's gyrus on average when compared to another group.

Is it correct to write that

> Type A participants have been reported to have larger Heschl's gyri's than type B participants.

Comment: Why the genetive (of gyri)?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence would be correct if you write "... to have larger Heschl's gyri ...". "Gyri" is the Latin plural of "gyrus" (both nominative).